# Having two or more matrices centered on one line

Tags: matrices

I have the following code:

```
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$ and $$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$.
```

But this is displayed on two lines. How can I make these matrices as well as text appear on the center of the page, all in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\text` to write text within displayed math. However, you'll have to handle the spacing inside the `\text` command, since spacing is ignored in math mode. Also, you'd want to move the final period inside the display math, to prevent it from appearing on a new line.

```
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\text{ and }
  B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
```

If you want more space between the matrices, try `\quad\text{and}\quad`.

(Note: you'll get slightly better spacing if you use `\[` and `\]` to begin/end display math instead of `$$`.)

Comment: Thank you. That was useful. How do I represent a matrix with \[ and \[ though? It transforms the matrix into the array

Comment: Not “slightly better”: `$$` should not be used in LaTeX. Ever.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want (`amsmath` package is used):

```
\[
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and }B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix} 
\]
```

Comment: You mean `\text`, rather than `text`, right?

Comment: @ArunDebray Certainly. Corrected. Thank you!